# Hibernate criterion Projection alias not being used

Tags: java, hibernate

Do Hibernate Projection aliases even work?  I could swear it just doesn't.  At least, it doesn't do what I would expect it to do.

Here is the java:

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(PersonProgramActivity.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.alias(Projections.sum("numberOfPoints"), "number_of_points"))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("person.id")))
    .setFirstResult(start)
    .setFetchSize(size)
    .addOrder(Order.desc("numberOfPoints"))
    .list();
```

Here is the SQL that it generates:

```
select
    sum(this_.number_of_points) as y0_,
    this_.person_id as y1_
from
    PERSON_PROGRAM_ACTIVITY this_
group by
    this_.person_id
order by
    this_.number_of_points desc
```

It doesn't seem to use the alias at all.  I would think setting the alias would mean that `sum(this_.number_of_points)` would be aliased as `number_of_points` and not `y0_`.  Is there some trick I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give the entire criteria an alias, then you can create other aliases that actually get used.  What is strange is that the aliases get turned into `y0_` instead of the other way around.

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(PersonProgramActivity.class, "ppa")
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.alias(Projections.sum("numberOfPoints"), "ppa.numberOfPoints"))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("person.id")))
    .setFirstResult(start)
    .setFetchSize(size)
    .addOrder(Order.desc("ppa.numberOfPoints"))
    .list();
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
select
    sum(this_.number_of_points) as y0_,
    this_.person_id as y1_
from
    PERSON_PROGRAM_ACTIVITY this_
group by
    this_.person_id
order by
    this_.y0_ desc
```

Comment: +1 i've seen this kind of thing as well, I think with subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

The query should be

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria( PersonProgramActivity.class, "ppa" )
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Projections.alias( Projections.sum( **"ppa.numberOfPoints"** ), **"numberOfPoints"** ) )
        .add( Projections.groupProperty( "person.id" ) ) )
    .setFirstResult( start )
    .setFetchSize( size )
    .addOrder( Order.desc( "ppa.numberOfPoints" ) )
    .list();
```